# How to connect Spring Mvc Controller 5 to jsp file?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 5.
I have got UserController.java:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String userForm(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.list());
        return "editUsers";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User formBackingObject() {
        return new User();
    }

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("users", userService.list());
            return "editUsers";
        }
        userService.save(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

I have got also class User.java:

```
public class User {
   public User() {
      this.name = "";
      this.email = "";
   }

   public User(String name, String email) {
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
   }

   private String name;
   private String email;

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getEmail() {
      return email;
   }
   public void setEmail(String email) {
      this.email = email;
   }
}
```

Interface UserService.java:

```
public interface UserService {
   void save(User user);

   List<User> list();
}
```

And UserServiceImp.java:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService {
   private List<User> listattt = new ArrayList<>();

   @Transactional
   public void save(User user) {
      listattt.add(user);
   }

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public List<User> list() {
       listattt.add(new User("a", "a@g.com"));
       listattt.add(new User("b", "b@g.com"));
       listattt.add(new User("c", "c@g.com"));
      return listattt;
   }
}
```

And EditUsers.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var myArray1 = "${users}";////----->>>> ERROR HOW TO CONNECT USER LIST FROM CONTROLLER TO JSP FILE
            var myTable= "<table><tr><td>User column</td>";
            for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
                myArray1[i] = myArray1[i].toFixed(3);
                myTable+="<tr><td> " + myArray1[i] + " </td>";
            }
            myTable+="</table>";
            document.write(myTable);
        </script>
</html>
```

Right now I would like to connect users list from UserController with editUsers.jsp and I don't know how to do it?
I was trying to do something like var myArray1 = "${users}"; but it didn't work. Generally I would like to have data from Java in JSP in Java Script. I would like to fill JS container myArray1 and based on this data do something next.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Try something like this `var myArray1 = <c:out value="${users}" />`

Comment: Yes, I would like to do something like this, but this code doesn't work unfortunately. I would like to have acces in JSP in JS from Java as you have written.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with JavaScript. Not directly, anyway. There is a hacky way to build the HTML with JavaScript, but you should rely on JSP's built in features.

You should use JSTL and use a `c:forEach` loop to build the table.

So, for example, you might do something like this:

```
<table>
  <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
     <tr><td>${user}</tr></td>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

In order to access individual fields, just use a dot operator, e.g. `${user.name}`. This will automatically call the getter of the field if it exists.

You include JSTL in your JSP file by putting this at the top.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

You may also need to include it as a dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that it is possible to do it in such way, but I would like to have access in JSP in Java Script from spring mvc from Java. I would like to fill container in JS from Java and then based on this container build a table.